# How to run swagger-ui with local code changes AND my own swagger.json?

Tags: docker, npm, swagger, swagger-ui

The Readme on https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui specifies that Swagger-UI can be run with your own file like this

```
docker run -p 80:8080 -e SWAGGER_JSON=/foo/swagger.json -v /bar:/foo swaggerapi/swagger-ui
```

which works I if I translate it to

```
docker build . -t swagger-ui-local && \
  docker run -p 80:8080 -e SWAGGER_JSON=/foo/my-file.json -v $PWD:/foo swagger-ui-local
```

This, however, ignores my local changes.

I can run my local changes with

```
npm run dev
```

but I can't figure out how to get this dev server to run anything else than the Petstore example.

Can anyone help me combine the two, so I can run swagger-ui with local code changes AND my own swagger.json?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out for `npm run dev`:

Place `my-file.json` in the `dev-helpers` folder. Then it's available from the search bar in on `http://localhost:3200/`.

To load it automatically when opening the server, alter `dev-helpers/index.html` by changing

```
url: "http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json"
```

to

```
url: "my-file.json"
```

Answer (score 16):

Make sure you are volume mounting the correct local directory.

Locally, I had my swagger config in `$PWD/src/app/swagger/swagger.yaml`. Running the following worked fine:

```
docker run -p 80:8080 -e SWAGGER_JSON=/tmp/swagger.yaml -v `pwd`/src/app/swagger:/tmp swaggerapi/swagger-ui
```

Simply refreshing the Swagger-UI page or clicking the "Explore" button in the header triggered a refresh of the data from my YAML file.

You can also specify `BASE_URL` excerpt from [swagger-installation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/installation.md)

`docker run -p 80:8080 -e BASE_URL=/swagger -e SWAGGER_JSON=/foo/swagger.json -v /bar:/foo swaggerapi/swagger-ui`

Comment: I finally got mine working following this post.  For others attempting this, you should point your browser at "localhost/index.html".

Comment: This worked fine for me. I just assumed that for a yaml file, the environment variable would change to SWAGGER_YAML but no, it's SWAGGER_JSON for both yaml and json. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I found this topic because I wanted to see a visual representation of my local swagger file, but could not seem to get swagger-ui (running in docker) to display anything other than the petstore.

Ultimately, my issue was with understanding the -e SWAGGER_JSON and -v flags, so I wanted to explain them here.

```
-v <path1>:<path2>
```

This option says "Mount the path <path1> from my local file system within the swagger-ui docker container on path <path2>"

```
-e SWAGGER_JSON=<filepath>
```

This option says "By default, show the swagger for the file at <filepath> using the docker container's file system."  The important part here, is that this filepath should take into account how you set <path2> above

Putting it all together, I ended up with the following:

```
docker run -p 8085:8080 -e SWAGGER_JSON=/foo/swagger.json -v `pwd`:/foo swaggerapi/swagger-ui
```

This says in english: "Run my swagger-ui instance on port 8085.  Mount my current working directory as '/foo' in the docker container.  By default, show the swagger file at '/foo/swagger.json'."

The important thing to note is that I have a file called swagger.json in my current working directory.  This command mounts my current working directory as /foo in the docker container.  Then, swagger UI can pick up my swagger.json as /foo/swagger.json.

Answer (score 9):

Here's how I ended up solving this, it also allows you to have multiple YML files:

```
docker run -p 80:8080 \                                                                                                                                 
  -e URLS_PRIMARY_NAME=FIRST \                                                                                                                             
  -e URLS="[ \                                                                                                                                           
    { url: 'docs/first.yml', name: 'FIRST' } \                                                                                                               
    , { url: 'docs/second.yml', name: 'SECOND' } \                                                                                                             
  ]" \                                                                                                                                                   
  -v `pwd`:/usr/share/nginx/html/docs/ \                                                                                                                 
  swaggerapi/swagger-ui
```

Comment: Clearly the most elegant/flexible solution of all - thanks! I didn't take that for granted ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you are running a maven project with Play Framework the following steps solved my issue :

1.) Alter the conf/routes file. Add the below line :
   GET   /swagger.json                 controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/swagger-ui",file="swagger.json")

2.) Add the swagger.json file to your Swagger-UI folder

so when you run the mvn project in a port example 7777, start the play server using mvn play2:run and then, localhost:7777/docs will automatically pull the Json file that is added locally.

Answer (score 1):

Docker compose solution:

create .env file and add the following:

```
URLS_PRIMARY_NAME=FIRST
URLS=[ { url: 'docs/swagger.yaml', name: 'FIRST' } ]
```

And create a docker-compose file with contents below:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
 swagger-ui:
  image: swaggerapi/swagger-ui
  container_name: "swagger-ui"
  ports:
    - "80:8080"
  volumes:
   - /local/tmp:/usr/share/nginx/html/docs/
  environment:
    - URLS_PRIMARY_NAME=${URLS_PRIMARY_NAME}
    - URLS=${URLS}
```

the swagger.yaml is at /local/tmp.

Answer (score 0):

For people facing this issue in mac, its a permission problem. By default after Catalina, docker doesn't have permission to allow its images to read local files in your system. Once its given it worked for me and it took my local swagger json file.

To grant privileges now, go to System preferences > Security & Privacy > Files and Folders, and add Docker for Mac and your shared directory.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another solution if you want to provide multiple URLs and from a specific folder (not default `/usr/share/nginx/html/docs/`):

```
docker run -p 80:8080 \
    -e SWAGGER_JSON=/docs/api.yaml \
    -e URLS="[ \
        { url: '/api1.yaml', name: 'API 1' }, \
        { url: '/api2.yaml', name: 'API 2' } \
    ]" \
    -v `pwd`/docs:/docs \
    swaggerapi/swagger-ui
```

Or for docker compose:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  swagger-ui:
    image: swaggerapi/swagger-ui
    volumes:
      - ./docs:/docs
    environment:
      SWAGGER_JSON: /docs/api.yaml
      URLS: '[{ url: "/api1.yaml", name: "API 1" }, { url: "/api2.yaml", name: "API 2" }]'
```

Please note, `SWAGGER_JSON` requires an absolute path, URLs in `URLS` require relative paths from the specified volume